# Backup MySQL database in ASP.NET MVC3

Tags: mysql, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

How do i backup MySql database from ASP.NET MVC3. The project is located in a local network server.

Thanks

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/backup-methods.html

Comment: As eggyal suggested go read about the backup command and execute it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use MySqlBackup.NET to perform the task

http://mysqlbackupnet.codeplex.com/

I'm one of the author of this project.